# T SQL cursor calculation based on previous rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [tblTEST] 
(
    RowID INT,
    SKU INT,
    Shop INT,
    Week INT,
    ShopPriority INT,    
    ShopStock INT,       
    Target_Stock INT,    
    Outbound INT,        
    Ration_Replen INT,   
    Open_Stk INT,        
    Closing_Stk INT,     
    Real_Open INT,       
    Unconst_Replen INT,     
    Rounded_Replen INT   
);
```

And populate with values:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblTEST
VALUES (1, 111, 100, 1, 1, 50, 50, 50, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0),
       (2, 111, 100, 1, 2, 50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
       (3, 111, 100, 1, 3, 50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
       (4, 111, 100, 1, 4, 50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

That creates the below (I couldn't get all the zero's in due to formatting issues on this page:

```
RowID     SKU     Shop    Week   Prioirty   ShopStock    Target_Stock   Outbound     Ration_Replen    Open_Stk    Closing_Stk    Real_Open    Unconst_Replen   Rounded_Replen
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1        111     100      1        1          50           50            50              0               5            5           5                               
  2        111     200      1        2          50           50            50              0                                                          
  3        111     300      1        3          50           50            50              0
  4        111     400      1        4          50           50            50
```

However, I need to perform a calculation to create the below:

```
    RowID     SKU     Shop    Week   Prioirty   ShopStock    Target_Stock   Outbound     Ration_Replen    Open_Stk    Closing_Stk    Real_Open    Unconst_Replen   Rounded_Replen
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1        111     100      1        1          50           50            50              0               5            5           5                               
      2        111     200      1        2          50           50            50              0               5            5           5                    
      3        111     300      1        3          50           50            50              0               5            5           5
      4        111     400      1        4          50           50            50              0               5            5           5
```

I'm using the below cursor to try and achieve this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentRow INT;
DECLARE @PreviousRow INT

DECLARE MinQty CURSOR FOR
    SELECT RowID
    FROM [tblTEST]
    WHERE [Week] IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY [SKU], [Week], ShopPriority

OPEN MinQty

FETCH NEXT FROM MinQty INTO @CurrentRow

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT [Open_Stk]
         FROM [tblTEST]
         WHERE RowID = @CurrentRow) IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [tblTEST]
        SET [Open_Stk] = (SELECT [Closing_Stk]
                          FROM [tblTEST]
                          WHERE RowID = @PreviousRow)
        WHERE RowID = @CurrentRow

        UPDATE [tblTEST]
        SET [Real_Open] = (SELECT IIF([Open_Stk] >= 0, [Open_Stk], 0)
                           FROM [tblTEST]
                           WHERE RowID = @CurrentRow),          
            [Unconst_Replen] = (SELECT IIF(ShopStock + [Ration_Replen] < Target_Stock, IIF(Target_Stock - (ShopStock + [Ration_Replen]) < [Real_Open], Target_Stock - (ShopStock + [Ration_Replen]), [Real_Open]), 0)
                                FROM [tblTEST]
                                WHERE RowID = @CurrentRow),                 
            Rounded_Replen = (SELECT IIF(Unconst_Replen = 0, 0, IIF(Unconst_Replen < Outbound, Outbound, Unconst_Replen))
                              FROM [tblTEST]
                              WHERE RowID = @CurrentRow),
            Closing_Stk = (SELECT Open_Stk - IIF(Rounded_Replen > IIF(Open_Stk >= 0, Open_Stk, 0), 0, Rounded_Replen)
                           FROM [tblTEST]
                           WHERE RowID = @CurrentRow)
        WHERE RowID = @CurrentRow
    END

    SET @PreviousRow = @CurrentRow

    FETCH NEXT FROM MinQty INTO @CurrentRow
END

CLOSE MinQty
DEALLOCATE MinQty
```

However, the cursor does not do anything - the values remain unchanged and Open_Stk \ Closing_Stk and Real_Open are not being calculated - what am I missing?

Comment: Why use a `CURSOR` in the first place? RBAR solutions are awfully slow in SQL Server, and other RDBMS. If you want to reference the "previous" row why not use `LEAD`/`LAG`?

Comment: The cursor only returns the @CurrentRow, your problem shouldn't be there but on the UPDATE [tblTEST]. Have you tried that UPDATE individually, for a single RowID, and verified that it does what you expect it to do ?.

Comment: @MarcGuillot the cursor returns the current row but the first UPDATE is WHERE RowID = PreviousRow

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the cursor for such scenario, if you need to do the calculation based on the previous row, you can use the SQL server inbuild functions - see below example as a reference and you can change it as per your requirement.

```
 SELECT tbl.RowID,
       tbl.SKU,
       tbl.Shop,
       tbl.Week,
       tbl.Prioirty,
       tbl.Replen,
       FIRST_VALUE(tbl.Open_Stk) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl.SKU ORDER BY tbl.RowID
                                     ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) -
       ISNULL(SUM(tbl.Replen) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl.SKU ORDER BY tbl.RowID
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS OpenStk
FROM (VALUES (1,111,100,1,1,300,5000),           
             (2,111,200,1,2,200,NULL),
             (3,111,300,1,3,100,NULL),
             (4,111,400,1,4,250,NULL))tbl(RowID,SKU,Shop,[Week],Prioirty,Replen,Open_Stk);
```

Comment: this helps, but not only is the calculation based on previous rows, these previous rows are also calculations

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I got it to work.  Silly really -

I just changed the below block:

```
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT [Open_Stk]
         FROM [tblTEST]
         WHERE RowID = @CurrentRow) IS NULL)
```

to

```
BEGIN
    IF (
            (
                SELECT [Open_Stk]
                FROM [tblTEST]
                WHERE RowID = @CurrentRow
                ) = 0
```

The default values are 0 not NULL.  Oh well, thank you to all those that provided a comment.